# Android: Format milliseconds into >60 seconds when no minute format is given

Tags: java, android, time, format, milliseconds

I got a millisecond value. I want to use a format string, to format those milliseconds into a time format. e.g. 45000ms = 45s or 0m 45s or whatever. So this is no special thing. I used SimpleDateFormat for this, but now comes my problem:

61000ms ends up in 1m 1s. This is okay for me, **IF** there is a minute given in the format string. But when there is no minute given in the format string, it should print out 61s instead of just 1s.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Currently I dont see it without doing any ugly string formatting code.

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks in advanced!
slain

Edit:

For better understanding:
you got 65400 milliseconds.

format string has minutes, seconds, milliseconds: 1m 5s 400ms
format string has minutes and seconds: 1m 5s
format string has seconds: 65s
format string has seconds and milliseconds: 65s 4ms
format string has minutes and milliseconds: 1m 5400ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are given a number of milliseconds, and a time format string, and need to produce a correctly formatted time? If not, ignore the rest of this...

Maybe not the BEST way, but kind of a nice waterfall: Convert the milliseconds to a set of integers for days, hours, minutes, seconds (or more, or less, depending on the expected range), and then iterate forward through the format string. If day is present, great, stick the number of days in there. If not, skip it, multiply by 24 and add to hours. Do the same for hours->minutes, minutes->seconds, and you should end up with it correctly formatted, even if with weird formats (like days and seconds but not minutes).

Comment: Yeah, you got what I mean. But this "iterate forward through the format string" sounds like the "ugly string formatting" I mentioned in my question :(

Comment: Simply check if .indexOf("M") == -1

Comment: I give this the status of "answer" because its the closest answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to convert but have a look at [time units](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you can parse milliseconds like so;

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date(millis))); // Prints 05 Aug 2011
}
```

Obviously, you can tweak the date format as necessary to display seconds, milliseconds, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying a normal formatting. I want to display minutes only if a minute is in the given format string. If there is no given minute in the format string then all seconds should be converted to seconds (if given in format string).